# Type non-ASCII chars using QTest

Tags: qt

I am trying to enter text in a Qt application using [`QTest::keyClicks()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#keyClicks). So far it is working great for english characters.

When I tried with non-ASCII chars like Hindi/Tamil/Japanese, app crashes with stack trace `QTest::asciiToKey(char)`. Looks like `QTest::keyClicks()` supports only latin chars.

Is there anyway I can enter non-ASCII chars?

Example code

```
void enterText(std::string aSentence)
{
  QTest::keyClicks(widget, QString::fromStdString(aSentence));
}

fApp->enterText("அ");
```

Comment: please post a [mcve] of your problem

Comment: I think you have to provide rather the keyboard's key sequence than the actual text. For English language it's probably correspond to the English keyboard keys, but for other languages it's not always true. For instance, if you want to print a character that normally printed by pressing F10 key, than you have to write: `QTest::keyClick(myWidget, Qt::Key_F10);`.

Comment: @vahancho Let me try and update

Comment: @vahancho I tried the approach by changing the system language to non-latin, so that if I can type non english characters. In this way I can successfully type the non-english characters. But by doing Qtest it just enters normal english character.

Comment: I was able to achieve the desire result with the lead given by @vahancho.  Instead of KeyClick i have used the QTest::sendKeyEvent method which does the job for me, since the asciiToKey operation performed before this function call. Code: `QTest::sendKeyEvent(QTest::KeyAction::Click, widget, Qt::Key_A, QString::fromUtf8(aSentence.c_str()), Qt::KeyboardModifier::NoModifier);`  Here we are passing random key along with text